# Send file as packages with Spring REST

Tags: spring, rest, networking

I would like to send a file as a response to a REST request.
I found a solution to do this, which works. (I found the code at Stack Overflow, but, sorry, I can't find anymore the link. I report it below.)

**My question is** that this process will send the file as packages? So if the recipient has a slow internet connection will receive a timeout (because the file was sent at once), or this is handled?

Thank you for your help.

The code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> downloadCompressed(@RequestParam("filename") String filename, HttpServletRequest request) {

    ResponseEntity respEntity = null;
    byte[] reportBytes = null;

    File result = new File(Configuration.OUTPUTDIR.getValue() + filename);
    try {
        if (result.exists()) {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(Configuration.OUTPUTDIR.getValue() + filename);
            String type = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(filename);
            byte[] out = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

            HttpHeaders responseHeader = new HttpHeaders();
            responseHeader.add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
            responseHeader.add("Content-Type", type);

            respEntity = new ResponseEntity(out, responseHeader, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            respEntity = new ResponseEntity("File Not Found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return respEntity;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return respEntity = new ResponseEntity("IO Exception", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I chose to encode the files with Base64 and send them in pieces as JSON files.